# Exchange 2003 set out of office message

Tags: exchange-2003, email

How to set an "out of office" message to a exchange 2003 user?

Comment: More info. Are you the user or the admin. Do you need help from outlook or OWA?

Comment: I'm the admin, i want to set it from Exchange 2003 not from Outlook. I haven't got the user password to access to his Outlook, but he forgot to set the out of office message.

Comment: YOu need to give your self permissions to the mailbox and add it to outlook. Simple.

Comment: Is it not possibile throw Exchange? Exists something like this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217.aspx for Exchange 2003 ?

Comment: You can do it via powershell but its ALOT easier from the GUI. Just give your self permissions to the mailbox, do the work. Remove permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up their mailbox in Outlook, or log into their OWA.

Comment: I haven't got his password, may I add to me full access to his mailbox, is this enought?

Comment: Should be, yes.